# MATLAB result is inappropriate

Tags: matlab

I'm new in MATLAB, i cannot get the answer in the format that i want. 
I have a basic function call, but every execution of the program gives the result in the following format  :

```
357341279027200000/23794118819840001
```

It's supposed to be in decimal, for example for same execution : `15.0181`.

I could not figure out why this is happening ? Can you help me, thank you !!

Answer (score 5):

Type [`format long`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/format.html) on the command prompt or in your script.

If that doesnt work because the value is too large, try using [`vpa`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/symbolic/vpa.html)

Answer (score 2):

Note that it's just visual, internally the value computed is precise.

```
>d  = 357341279027200000/23794118819840001
d =
   15.0181
>> d * 23794118819840001 == 357341279027200000
ans =
     1
>> 15.0181 * 23794118819840001 == 357341279027200000
ans =
     0
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you are not using format rat (rational). This is the reason why you may be having fractional values. If you want decimals, try format long or format long g (Long g provides the optimal length and accuracy as a decimal, up to 10 places.)